# Splitting strings by newline trouble

Tags: java, regex, sockets, netbeans, split

I am reading in a file that is being sent though a socket and then trying to split it via newlines (\n), when I read in the file I am using a byte[] and I convert the byte array to a string so that I can split it.

```
public String getUserFileData()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        is.close();

        return new String(mybytearray);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }

    return "";
}
```

Here is the code used to attempting to split the String

```
public void readUserFile(String userData, Log logger)
{
    String[] data;
    String companyName;

    data = userData.split("\n");

    username = data[0];
    password = data[1].toCharArray();
    companyName = data[2];
    quota = Float.parseFloat(data[3]);

    company = new Company();            
    company.readCompanyFile("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ArFile\\ArFile Clients\\" + companyName + "\\"
            + companyName + ".cmp");

    cloudFiles = new CloudFiles();
    cloudFiles.readCloudFiles(this, logger);
}
```

It causes this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: What's your question/trouble/problem/doubt???

Comment: Wrap the stream with `BufferedReader`, there is a readLine method.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit. Now kindly tell us ***which line*** is the cause of this exception? Also does your code really have empty catch blocks?

Comment: Yes, what @nhahtdh recommends is the right way to do this. His comment should be an answer. 1+

Comment: @nhahtdh please put this as an answer and ill vote it

Comment: also how do I wrap the stream with a BufferedReader exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method in [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) class.

Wrap the `InputStream` under `InputStreamReader`, and wrap it under `BufferedReader`:

```
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Please also check the encoding of the stream - you might need to specify the encoding in the constructor of `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: That wasn't what was actually causing my issue, but ill mark it as the answer because it would have been better to do this way. I have since solved my issue, it was just sillyness on my part

Answer (score 3):

As stated in comments, using a `BufferedReader` would be best - you should be using an `InputStreamReader` anyway in order to convert from binary to text.

```
// Or use a different encoding - whatever's appropriate
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
try {
    String line;
    // I'm assuming you want to read every incoming line
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        processLine(line);
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Note that it's important to state which encoding you want to use - otherwise it'll use the platform's default encoding, which will vary from machine to machine, whereas presumably the data *is* in one specific encoding. If you don't know which encoding that is yet, you need to find out. Until then, you simply can't reliably understand the data.

(I hope your real code doesn't have an empty catch block, by the way.)